# Angular 6 window scroll callback function not updating html view

Tags: angular, scroll

I am new to angular 6 and creating an application in angular 6 . There I have a button 'back to top' which is to scroll the page to top of the page. The CSS of this button is given below :

```
#scrollToTopBtn {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 30px;
    z-index: 99;
    font-size: 18px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background-color: cadetblue;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 4px;
  }

  #scrollToTopBtn:hover {
    background-color: #555;
  }
```

I have implemented this button for the data fetched using ngx-infinite-scroll.

```
<ul class="list-group" infiniteScroll
            [infiniteScrollDistance]="2"
            [infiniteScrollThrottle]="50"
            (scrolled)="onScroll()"
           (scrolledUp)="onScrollUp()"
            [scrollWindow]="true">
```

And this button will be visible only when the model variable displayScrollToTopButton is set to true

```
<div  *ngIf="displayScrollToTopButton">
        <input id="scrollToTopBtn" type="button" class="btn" (click)="ScrollToTop()" value="Back to top">
      </div>
```

Also I am setting this button to visible only if the count of the data bind with the ngx-infinite-scroll control is greater than some threshold value.its working fine. And also , on click of the button , I am scroll to the top of the page and make the button invisible like below :

```
    ScrollToTop(){
        document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
        this.displayScrollToTopButton = false;
      }
onScroll(){
    //my business logic to fetch data from API
    this.displayScrollToTopButton = this.searchResult.length > this.itemsCountPerPage;
  }
```

It works fine till now. But I am facing problem to achieve following two scenarios, 
1. When the page is scrolled up manually (not by using the 'back to top' button), the 'back to top' button should be hidden. I have tried following code, but its not working(function toggleBackToTopButton is executing, but updated displayScrollToTopButton variableis not reflecting in the html)

```
ngOnInit() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.toggleBackToTopButton, false);
  }

  toggleBackToTopButton(){
    console.log(document.body.scrollTop + " " +document.documentElement.scrollTop);
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 300 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 300) {
      this.displayScrollToTopButton = true;
    } else {
      this.displayScrollToTopButton = false;
    }
    console.log(this.displayScrollToTopButton);
  }
```

2. Once the page is completely scrolled down and all the data is fetched from the API, if we are scrolling back to top of the page and scroll back down, the 'back to top' button is not visible.
   Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems to me you are having trouble with the `window.scroll`. Try using `Observable.fromEvent(window, "scroll").subscribe(e => {});` or `@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])onWindowScroll($event) {}`

Comment: also your requirements are pretty simple 1) scroll to top and 2) toggle the scroll-to-top button, you could do it simply by using the default javascript `window.scrollTo(0, 0)`.